# Datagridview multilpe links

Tags: c#, datagridview, hyperlink

I have a datagridview with 3 links in it, I want to be able to click the link and have it open up, I did make use of this

```
        private void Dgv_View_Employees_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {              
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.Dgv_View_Employees.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                string filenametodisplay = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                string targetPath = @"C:\root";
                string open = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath + filenametodisplay);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(open);
            }
        }
```

and it works fine if there is only one link, the problem is, it seems to open the first link and ignores the rest, what do I need to change to open the link in the correct cell ?

Comment: Are there 3 cells with a link in each cell or are there three links in one cell? What type of datagridviewcell do you use? what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's 3 cells each with a link, I used DataGridViewLinkColumns and tried it with DataGridViewTextBoxColumns, they do open the link but they only open the 1st one, doesn't matter on which one I click, I tried to assign the specific cell to a variable with the idea of having    if()    statements to compare it to a number range of some sort, but I didn't have any success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataGridViewCellEventArgs.ColumnIndex](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.columnindex(v=vs.80).aspx) property to gets a value indicating the column index of the cell that the event occurs for.

For example, if you have URL in column 8, 10 and 14:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 8 || e.ColumnIndex == 10 || e.ColumnIndex == 14)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = this.Dgv_View_Employees.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string filenametodisplay = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        string targetPath = @"C:\root";
        string open = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath + filenametodisplay);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(open);
    }
}
```